# WSO2 api manager mediation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm using apim 2 and I need to route client call to the back end service dynamically at runtime.

I have added a custom sequence in the folder WSOAM_HOME\repository\resources\customsequences\in

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="mySeq">
    <class name="org.wso2.carbon.env.EnvironmentResolver"/> 
</sequence>
```

I have  added the   jar containing my  implementation  under repository/component/lib.

I have configured my API to use this custom sequence throught the publisher portal,but The problem is that the **EnvironmentResolver**  is not being called!!

Did i  miss any thing?

Comment: Do you get any error when server starup or invoking that api ? Did you publish the api once you selected it through publisher portal?

Comment: Hi  Jenananthan,I didn't get any exception, i noticed that my custom sequence is well deployed under WSOrepository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\api_HOME\ but i don't know why it not being called.For publishing it, yes i'm using the publisher portal

Comment: Add this to your sequence and see if you see the log entry in console?
`<log level="full" />`

Comment: you customer sequence should be deployed in <APIM_HOME>repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences

Comment: It works now!! thanks  Jenananthan and Bhathiya.
A last question plz, I'm using dynamic endpoint when publishing my API, I need than to set **To** header , i'm using this code but it looks not working:
`EndpointReference endpointReference=new EndpointReference("http://localhost:8080/myBackendUrl");  
  axis2MessageContext.setTo(endpointReference);`
Is this the right way to set th **TO** Header?
ANd can i access user information (username,role) inside my AbstractMediator implementation ?

Comment: Setting to header looks fine.
To get username see http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html
For role, you need to enable JWT and read X-JWT-Assertion header

Comment: Please post an answer on how you resolved original issue. That will be helpful to others.